# slick js and animation for slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slick.js

I use [slick js](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) and I want add animation for slide.

How to do to the previous slide moved to the left and another on his pestering faster right?

When you click the arrow previous, I would like to overlap the previous slide quickly from right, and seen moving slowly to the right.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you are trying to do? Also there seems to be pretty good documentation on examples slick.js has -- what have you tried from those?

Comment: See this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37424378/slick-slider-css-animation-flashes